# Eclipse SWT CompositeScroll to always show vertical bar

Tags: eclipse, swt

Is it possible to ALWAYS show the VerticalBar even though there is nothing to scroll?

```
ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(main, SWT.BORDER_SOLID| SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

This line of code does not always have the scroll on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a ScrolledComposite I don't think you can do this, at least if you want to have the H scroll function normally. You can call the `ScrolledComposite.setAlwaysShowScrollbars()` to true, but then it will show both of the enabled scrollbars all the time. (They are enabled by setting the SWT.H_SCROLL or SWT.V_SCROLL in the options). If you don't ever want horizontal scrolling then this will do what you want.

Comment: Please see my edit. Even if I have the option, the verticalbar is not shown until there is "stuffs" to be scrolled.

Comment: ahhs! how could I have missed that method out.. thanks for your help!